# rsync all files recursively - exclude all folders (but not their contents)

Tags: command-line, rsync

I have a a folder called `files`  that contains a lot of subfolders.

These subfolder either has videofiles in them or another folder with video files in them.

So tree structure looks something like this:

```
subfolder/video.mp4
subfolder2/video1.mp4
subfolder2/anothersubfolder/video2.mp4
```

I now want to copy all the video files with rsync to my `vids` folder, only the video files. I can't figure out how to do it.

This is what I have tried:

```
rsync -avztr --delete /home/pi/ftp/data/files/ /home/pi/vids/ --include=*.mp4 --include=*.m4v --exclude=*/
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

It seams like every time I try to exclude a folder, i can't get the files in the folder - which makes sense.

Comment: Do you just want to transform your arborescence into a flat directory containing all those videos and no subdirectory at all? The question isn't very clear about the intent. Also, is there a good reason you require rsync to do it?

Comment: Yes that is what I want to do. Copy all video files from all sub dirs into one flat destination dir. @A.B The reason I want to use rsync is simply because the files are located on another server, I want to run this sync script every 15 mins, syncing ALL changes - getting new files, deleting removed files etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose building a staging, local, flat, directory first, filled only with symlinks (you could even fill it with hardlinks if it's in the same filesystem) to the actual files, then rsync it instead of the "original", using option -L to transfer the actual file, not the symlink.

```
#!/bin/sh

rm -rf /home/pi/staging
mkdir /home/pi/staging
find /home/pi/ftp/data/files -type f '(' -name '*.mp4' -o -name '*.m4v' ')' -print0 | xargs -0r ln -s -t /home/pi/staging
# rsync -a = rsync -rlptgoD but -L is needed instead of -l. Perhaps -aL has the same effect as -rLptgoD
rsync -rLptgoDvztr --delete /home/pi/staging/ /home/pi/vids/ --include='*.mp4' --include='*.m4v'
```

By the way, this won't work in case of collision with multiple files in different subdirectories having the same name (here `ln -s` will complain), but that's outside the scope of the question.

Comment: That s a great idea! I will try it out on Monday.

Comment: Hmm for some reason this does not work for me. I think it is because I'm using curlfs to mount the remote share /home/pi/ftp/ the find command simply never completes. Thanks a lot for the suggestion though

Comment: Do you have any find command that succeeds at all? like `find /home/pi/ftp/data/files -type d` (to have the tree of directories) ? Any warning about inodes or a loop detected? Or can you witness some kind of loop in the output? If it's possible, would switching to sshfs change anything?